# Ruby using namespace/module

Tags: ruby, class, module, namespaces, net-http

For example:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/some_path?query=string')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

What is the correct/rubist way to get rid of `Net::HTTP` ? i.e. `HTTP::Get.new()` or just `Get.new()`

Comment: @sawa don't remove the tag `net-http`.It is needed for future search on `SO`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to shorten these, you can just import that namespace:

```
Net::HTTP.start(...)

include Net
# HTTP.start(...)
```

Be careful when you import aggressively as it might cause conflict within your class if you get carried away.

An alternative is to create aliases:

```
HTTP = Net::HTTP
Get = Net::HTTP::Get
```

The "correct" way is to just spell it out and not get too flustered by that. A typical Ruby program will bury this sort of low-level behavior beneath an abstraction layer so it's rarely a big deal.

Comment: I can't `include Net::HTTP`, it throws error: `TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)`

Comment: Ah, I should remove that then. `include` only works on modules, but it's hard to tell how these things are structured by just looking at use cases. Aliases might work better. In any case, typing `Net::HTTP` is something that makes it abundantly clear what you're doing, and hiding that is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this example will clarify things.

```
module Foo
  def foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

Bar.new.foo # foo
Bar.new.bar # bar

class Baz
  extend Foo

  self.def baz
    "baz"
  end
end

Baz.foo # foo
Baz.baz # baz
```

Make sure you know what you are doing when you use import or extend. You could end up overriding a method that you might not want to override.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://example.com/some_path?query=string')

httpns = Net::HTTP

def get(uri)
   httpns::Get.new uri
end

http.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = get uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```

in your class.